# Pasar variables dentro de un for en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código para pasar parámetros a una función:

```
function updateBar(id, type, title, idDash, urls){
    for(var i in urls){
      var url = urls[i].url+'/'+id;
      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var dataHarvest = data['return'];
        if(type === "Bar"){
          barChart(dataHarvest, title, type, idDash, urls[i].id, urls);
        }
      }); 
    }
  }
```

`urls` es un objeto que me trae links de consulta y sus id (Estos links son traídos de una base de datos).

Al hacer el recorrido con el `for`, funciona bien porque me consulta cada `url` que le estoy enviando y obtiene el `data` de cada consulta que se esta haciendo.

El problema es que quiero a la función `barChart()` enviarle cada uno de los `ids` del objeto `urls` pero sólo me envía el último, del resto de opciones esta muy bien.

Lo que me doy cuenta es que a pesar de estar la petición `GET` dentro de un for, no tiene en cuenta el recorrido. es decir:

Al hacer un `console.log(urls[i].id);` debería traerme `1 2 3` que son los id, pero sólo me trae `3`

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de obtener todos los id al hacer el recorrido del for o si existe una manera diferente de hacer esta función que estoy planetando.

Comment: Solo cambia `var url` por `let url`.

Comment: Sería `for(let i in urls){` en lugar de `let url`

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo?, no había escuchado del let!

Comment: @FabianSierra Ya escribí una respuesta que toca el tema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un problema clásico que tiene que ver con que `$.getJSON` es una función asíncrona, entonces cuando se ejecuta el código del éxito, los valores de las variables ya no coinciden con los valores que había en el momento en el que se hizo la llamada a `$.getJSON`.

Una posible solución sería crear una clausura (*closure* en inglés) y de este modo crear un ámbito especial que hará que se preserven los valores. Algo como esto:

```
function updateBar(id, type, title, idDash, urls){
    for(var i in urls){
        (function(i) {
            var url = urls[i].url;
            $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                var dataHarvest = data['return'];
                if(type === "Bar"){
                    barChart(dataHarvest, title, type, idDash, urls[i].id, urls);
                }
            }); 
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: O usar `let` en lugar del closure.

Comment: @MitsuGami Sí, podrías usar `let`, OP tendría que definir una variable nueva y asignarle el valor de `i`. Deberías poner eso como respuesta

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro es muy buena. Con la llegada de ES6, los closures **en este caso** se pueden evitar usando `let` en la variable de control en lugar de `var`.

```
for(let url in urls) { ... }
```

La razón de esto es porque cuando declaras una variable con `var` esta no depende del bloque en donde se le declara, si no, su ámbito es *la función* en donde se ecuentra. En otras palabras, `var url` **trasciende** el for, y cuando llega el turno de recibir el callback, el bucle ya terminó su iteración. lo que no tiene mucho sentido si lo piensas...

```
(function a() {
  {
    var e = 123;
  }
  console.log(e); // imprime 123
})();
```

Por el contrario, `let` si usa un scope de "bloque", lo cual lo limita al bloque en donde se le declara.

```
(function call(urls) {
  for(let url of urls) {
    $.getJSON(url, (resp) => {
      console.log(url); // mira lo que imprime
    });
  }
})(['http://api.fixer.io/latest', 
    '/api/arenas', 
    '/examples/avatar-api']);
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta y dejaría el código más limpio. Una nota: el problema que @Fabian tiene es con el índice `i` y no con la url (que realmente no se usa cuando se reciben los resultados del `$.getJSON`). En el código de Fabian, bastaría con cambiar `for(var i in urls){` con `for(let i in urls){` y ya funcionaría perfecto.

Comment: Así es @AlvaroMontoro +1

Comment: Que buen aporte @MitsuGami, aprendí muchas cosas :)

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo verificar que las peticiones se realizan correctamente..

puedes verificarlo agregando un `console.log(url);` antes del `$.getJSON(url, function(data){` Tal vez el problema sea que no se completa la petición, tratar de ver si todo va bien con algo como esto:

```
console.log("Enviando peticion a: " + url);
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var dataHarvest = data['return'];
        if(type === "Bar"){
          barChart(dataHarvest, title, type, idDash, urls[i].id, urls);
        }
}).error(function() { console.log("Error en obtener datos: " + url); });
```

Comment: Si se estan haciendo las peticiones bien, al hacer `console.log(urls[i].id)` antes del `$.getJSON()` me traer cada uno de los `ids`, dentro de la petición no.

Comment: Probaste mirando las peticiones y su respuesta en el monitor de peticiones del navegador? (F12->network / red)

Comment: Si y cada petición que se hace en el ciclo me trae los datos bien

Comment: Ok, ninguna da error, y todas se envian, quiere decir que todas se deben recibir.. ¿Probaste mirando el contenido de la variable type? , y pues, tambien digo que pruebeces con `if(type == "Bar"){`